# Intelligent method for particular traversing of a matrix

Tags: java, matrix, traversal

I have to traverse an `n x n` matrix in java (so indices are 0,...,n-1), to assign values to the single elements. I must start from the bottom right and arrive to the top left. The particularity is that I do not have to consider the `matrix[n-1][n-1]` element, that has been initialised before. The adjacent values depend on each other for initialazing and it must be initialized first.

One way could be inserting an `if` in the `for` cycle

```
for (i = n-1; i >= 0; i--)
  for (j = n-1; j >= 0; j--)
    if (i == n - 1 && j == n - 1)
      //initialize particular value
    else
      //initialize others
```

but it seems to me a bit inefficient.

Another way could be to initialize the value `matrix[n-1][n-1]` outside the cycle, then doing 3 `for` cycles (one for the bottom line, one for the rightest column, one for the other elements). But it seems a bit inelegant.

So I'm searching, if exists, for a solution that involves only two annidate `for`, and without a control in every cycle (like first example).

Comment: store the value befor the nested for, and reatribute after the for loops?

Comment: No. The init of adjacent elements depends on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution of Joakim is good except the % and / operations... inspired to this, I've found an interesting variant that avoid them. I've called column index `j1` to avoid problems with other "normal" cycles.

```
matrix[n-1][n-1] = //init code;
int j1 = n-2;

    for (int i = n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (; j1 >= 0; j1--) {
            matrix[i][j1] = //init code;
        }
        j1 = n-1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that uses one loop through the matrix which makes it easy to avoid matrix[n-1][n-1]. Not sure how the calculations compares to an if though from a performance perspective

```
int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];

int current = n * n - 2;
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
while (current >= 0) {
    col = current % n;
    row = current / n;

    matrix[row][col] = //init stuff
    current--;
}
```